# Problems with prediction in decision tree in caret package

Tags: prediction, r-caret, rpart

I am having problems doing a prediction with decision trees (CART).

I have this code:

```
training <- read.csv("pml-training.csv", header=TRUE)
set.seed(1972)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y=training2$classe, p=0.6, list=FALSE)
wk_training <- training2[inTrain,]
wk_testing <- training2[-inTrain,]
```

wk_trainng dataset has 11776 vars and wk_testing 7846.

```
set.seed(1972)
model_dt <- train(wk_training$classe ~ ., data = wk_training,  method="rpart")
print(model_dt, digits=3)
```

Run against wk_testing

```
predictions_dt <- predict(model_dt, newdata=wk_testing)
```

Then I expect predictions_dt to have 7846 rows as it has wk_testing,
but predictions_dt has only 165 rows ????

I don't know what I am doing wrong...

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is `training2` variable defined in your code? Have you maybe made a typo in your code and use wrong variable?

Comment: I create training2 from training like this:
nzv <- nearZeroVar(training, saveMetrics=TRUE)

# eliminate near zero values
cols <- nzv$nzv == FALSE

training2 <- training[,cols]

Answer (score 0):

If you have missing values, the `predict` function defaults to `na.action = na.omit`. You can test to see if this is the issue using `na.action = na.fail`. If this is the case, you might want to impute. See the `preProcess` option in `train`.